# Meteor.js: Doing message dependency like most of chat nowadays

Tags: javascript, meteor, chat

What is the best way to do a message dependency in chat where the next message will not show the image of the user if the previous message was sent by the same user? I tried my best doing it in the client where I get all the messages, then loop it before returning it to the client. But sometimes get mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

You could include a field called `clientCreateDate` or something, where you save the moment the message was submitted *on the client.* Then display all messages with the appropriate sort. If the prior message was sent by the same user hide the avatar with a class.

This might create instances where another users' message appears earlier in the list than one you just sent, but beyond that you'd always know which message was created first, regardless of when it hit the server.

Comment: "If the prior message was sent by the same user hide the avatar with a class." How would I get the prior message?

Comment: I might start with something like `<div class="{{newPerson}} ... "></div>` for the avatar. Then register `newPerson` as a helper that queries the db to see who the last speaker was, and returns a class or null as appropriate. [The tutorial app](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/update-and-remove) does something similar but with an if-statement.